# Sitefinity- Change template of a group page or redirection page

Tags: progress, sitefinity

I have created template in sitefinity, later I decided to create new template and change all templates for pages, I was able to change layout for pages but their is no option for changing layout for group page,

I want to change group page layout because I am not able to delete the previous template as its bounded with it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wierd, i wonder if it’sa bug and get used to be a page

Go into its properties (not page edit), change the page type to be a regular page (not group). NOW edit the page, change the template… and then go back to properties and make it a group page again.

Comment: yeah this was the only  way, i have to move all their child pages to different group and then change layout of this, and then delete.. Sitefinity has soo many things to improve.

Comment: Why would you have to move all the child pages? Just change the group to regular and back…? Regular pages can still have children.

Comment: actually the layout was holding the page, we accidently created and worked on new layout. Deleting old layout was mandatory.